# Ideas on detecting holofoil trading cards?

Tags: image-processing

I'm relatively new to image processing but am working on a trading card sorting machine, and would like to detect holographic cards. I'm currently identifying cards using ORB matching (moved from p-hashing the cards) and the current system works quiet well. The issue is I cannot identify holofoil cards as being holofoil.

My vague idea is to take multiple pictures of the same card with different light angles, and compare somehow, but can't figure a way to do so. Any hint or idea I can pursue would be greatly appreciated! I've done my fair share of googling but fear I just don't know *what* to google to read more on.
Thank you in advance!

3 Example cards (though the input would be one card on a full white background) with different types of holofoil (full foil, foil art, and reverse-foil).

[image: Top Light]
[image: Left Light]
[image: Right Light]

Answer (score 2):

This is probably going to take trial and error on your part.  The things I'd try:

- **Different light angles**: use LEDs at different incident angles to illuminate the cards.
- **Different light colors**: Use red, green, blue, and infrared LEDs to illuminate the cards.
- **Polarizing filter**: use a polaroid filter (sunglasses might do) at different angles (rotations) in front of the camera when taking the picture.
- **Different camera**: use an infrared camera (or remove the IR filter that might be on your existing camera).

The trick will be to see what type of card is easiest to determine from what combination of illumination / camera / acquisition.